# Error: Unresolved reference while declaring variable in if-else

Tags: kotlin

Imagine I have some function like this:

```
fun dummyFunction():Int{
   if(True){
       val a = 1
   } else {
       val a = 2 
   }
   return a
}
```

Stack trace (from LeetCode):

```
Line 7: Char 11: error: unresolved reference: a
        return a
               ^
```

Why this code gives `unresolved reference: a` error? Every help is appreciated

P.S. I know how to solve this. But I got curious about this very situation

Comment: add a stack trace of the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is for scope of variables

The "a" variable just exist in {} of the if and the else
Way to fix this problem is define the "a" in out of if-else